# Getting error when issuing Spark-Submit command

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Im trying to run a spark-submit command and its reporting a syntax error, but I cant see what the issue is.  Here is the error message:

```
user@xxxxxxxx4 bin % spark-submit mnmcount.py data/mnm_dataset.csv
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/12/23 10:41:29 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
  **File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Downloads/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/mnmcount.py", line 7
    print("Usage: mnmcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
user@xxxxxxxx4 bin %
```

and here is the associated python code snippet

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: mnmcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: You need to set your environment to use an earlier version of Java.

Comment: Your syntax is for Python 3, but you perhaps used python2 in spark-submit, resulting in a syntax error. Set the correct environment variables for pyspark python.

Comment: @Hitobat. Thanks, im using version 8 which I believe is the proper version?

Comment: You can run `bash -x spark-submit` and see what the scripts are setting for JAVA_HOME. We had a similar problem on our cloudera cluster.